# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'debug' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, login, atributos, modulos

Estoy estudiando algunas cosas nuevas de Python que nunca vi. En este caso el módulo `logging`. Pero al importarlo me da un error que no se como solucionar.

Este es mi código:

```
import logging

logging.debug("This is a debug message")
logging.info("This is an info message")
logging.warning("This is a warning message")
logging.error("This is an error message")
logging.critical("This is a critical message")
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\python\logging.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "c:\...\python\logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logging.debug("This is a debug message")
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'debug' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

¿Por qué me dice que está parcialmente iniciado el módulo y que no tiene el atributo `debug`? También me pasa lo mismo con los demás atributos: `info`, `warning`, `error`, `critical`.

Intenté también usando `from logging import *` y `from logging import debug, info, warning, error, critial`. Pero tampoco me funciona.

Gracias, y saludos.

Comment: Puede ser porque el archivo donde estás importando logging también se llama logging, probá de cambiarle el nombre al archivo, así python no tiene conflictos a la hora de decidir cuál logging importar.

Comment: Paso a confirmar lo que dice @favcau y agregar un par de enlaces con tu mismo problema para que les eches una leída [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825041/attributeerror-module-logging-has-no-attribute-basicconfig?noredirect=1&lq=1), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482587/module-object-has-no-attribute-basicconfig) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762996/how-to-fix-attributeerrorpartially-initialized-module)

Comment: Muchas gracias @favcau, era eso, no me di cuenta. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es debido a que estás realizando el import del módulo logging, pero los archivos en el directorio actual de trabajo tienen precedencia, por lo que estarías importando el fichero logging.py (mismo fichero desde donde estás haciendo el import según la traza):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>     File "c:...\python\**logging.py**", line 1, in <module> 
>         import logging   
>     File "c:...\python\**logging.py**", line 3, in <module>
>         logging.debug("This is a debug message") 
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'debug' (most likely due
> to a circular import)

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso, no me di cuenta. Saludos!